# How do I find an exact string in the line of a file in Python?

Tags: python, string, search, io

This is for a script that pre-processes CFD input files on a server to submit jobs. I currently have a Python code to do this, but one file that I need to alter is giving me issues.

The file is a space-separated two column data file:

> HEADER X
>
> HEADER Y
>
> -400.0 1
>
> -320.0 0.1
>
> -280.0 0.01
>
> 0.0 0.001
>
> blah blah blah rest of file

I am only interested in finding, and changing the string "0.0" to something new, such as "2.0", "-1.0", or "3.0", or whatever. The code that I have now already knows that "0.0" is the string of interest, and searches for it in the files and replaces it with another number. This has been successfully done in other CFD input files.

However, in this particular file, as there are no alphabet strings that I can use for keywords for jumping to, I have to search for occurrences of "0.0". And the issue is that my code currently replaces the first occurrences of "0.0" with, say, "1.0". So the code becomes:

> HEADER X
>
> HEADER Y
>
> -400.0 1
>
> 1.0 0.1
>
> -280.0 0.01
>
> 0.0 0.001
>
> blah blah blah rest of file

The code that I currently use is:

```
with open('file.in','r') as file:
    for line in file:                                                                
        if '-400.0' in line: # jump to first instance of "-400.0"
            for line in file:
                if str(spk) in line: # in this case, spk = 0.0
                    orispkline = line #save the line with "0.0"
                    newspkline = line.replace(str(line.split([0]),str(newspk)) # replace "0.0" with "1.0"
                    break # jump out of the loop as the job is done
    file.seek(0) # go back to start of file:
        filedata = file.read() # read the file again 
        filedata = filedata.replace(str(orispkline),str(newspkline)) # replace the old line with the updated line

with open('file.in','w') as file:
    file.write(filedata) # write the file
```

So what happens is that it sees the "0.0" in "-320.0", and just replaces it. What I'd like is that the code goes through line by line, finds "0.0" that occurs by itself and is at the start of the line, and replaces it with the desired number.

I know the code is really round-about and can be optimized, but it works with all the other files, and I want to keep things simple and consistent.

Note: the string to search is not always "0.0", but a crank angle of "0.0" is always the one that gives me the most trouble.

Thank you all for your help!

Comment: why do you iterate over file twice?

Comment: `"0.0"` is always in 6-th row. You don't have to search it.

Comment: you could also try `if  line.startswith("0.0 ")` or `if line[:4] == "0.0 ":`

Comment: Do a regex search and replace on "^0.0" for "0.1"

Comment: @OlvinRoght The first iteration is the search and find the spark timing (this case is 0.0), then store the line. Then replace the 0.0 with the updated spark timing, and store it as a new line. Then second iteration is to read in the file, and replace the particular line altogether.

Comment: @furas In this case, it's the 6th row, but it's not necessarily the case all the time. Neither is the number of the 2nd column always going to be 0.001.

Comment: is it always in first colimn ? then use `if line.startswith("0.0 ")` or `if line[:4] == "0.0 ":` - in `"0.0 "` is space at the end.

Comment: @user3654549, I still don't understand why you iterate over file and after you found line with `'-400.0'` you launch loop again

Comment: @OlvinRoght, when I wrote the script, this was the way it worked for me, so that's what I used. I'm merely an engineer, not a programmer by trade. What method would you suggest as an alternative?

Comment: @user3654549, I don't clearly understand what do you want this code to do. Could you please provide **Input** and **Output**.

Comment: @OlvinRoght The input and output is shown in the main question. I want to read in that file, change 1 number, then write over that file again with the updated number. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thanks to the suggestion by furas in the comments above. I changed the line:

```
if str(spk) in line:
```

to

```
if line.startswith(spk):
```

where "spk" is the spark timing converted to string. That worked for all the cases that I tested, and successfully identified the correct line to make the replacement.

Thank you all for the discussion, and especially to furas.